# Angular Js Validation on Partial Views

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Index Page

```
 @model AngularMVC.Models.Employee
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<style>
    input.ng-touched.ng-invalid {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    input.ng-touched.ng-valid 
    {
        border: 1px solid #48bb00;
    }

   li{
       border:1px solid blue;
       font-size:2em;
       color:Green;
   }
</style>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Custom/modules.js"></script>

<div  ng-app="myApp">
    <form ng-controller="validateCtrl"
          name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="submit()">
        <span ng-show="isViewLoading">
            <img src="~/Content/images/box.gif" /> loading...
        </span>
        <div class="{{status}}">{{message}}</div>
        <p>
            <b>Name:</b> <br>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @ng_required = "true", ng_model = "Model.name", Name = "name" })
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.name.$dirty && myForm.name.$invalid">
                <span ng-show="myForm.name.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
            </span>
        </p>

        <p>
            <b>Email:</b><br>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @ng_required = "true", ng_model = "Model.email", Name = "email", type = "email" })
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
                <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
                <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
            </span>
        </p>

        <p>
            <b>Password:</b><br />
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { ng_model = "Model.password", @ng_required = "true", @class = "form-control", ng_minlength = "8", ng_maxlength = "16", Name = "password" })
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.password.$dirty && myForm.password.$invalid">
                <span ng-show="myForm.pass.$error.required">Password is required.</span>
                <span ng-show="myForm.password.$touched && myForm.password.$error.minlength">Passord must be 8-16 character</span>
                <span ng-show="myForm.password.$touched && myForm.password.$error.maxlength">Passord must be 8-16 character</span>
            </span>
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </form>
    @*<p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

    <a href="#first">First</a>*@
    <a href="#second">Second</a>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            {{PanelHeading}}
        </div>
        <div ng-view class="panel-body">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Module.js

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('validateCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.submit = function () {
        //$scope.model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        $scope.isViewLoading = true;
        $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "/Home/Create",
            data: { emp: $scope.Model }
        }).success(function (data, status, header, config) {

            if (data = "Success") {
                $scope.status = "text-success";
                $scope.message = "Data successfully submitted";
            }
            else {
                $scope.status = "text-warning";
                $scope.message = "Failed to insert Data";
            }

        }).error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            $scope.status = "text-danger";
            $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error while saving data!!';
        });
        $scope.isViewLoading = false;
    }
});

// Routes Provider for SPA
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/first', {
        templateUrl: '/Home/first',
        controller: 'HomeController',

    })
    .when('/second', {
        templateUrl: '/Home/Second',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })
    });
```

Partial View Having a signup form

```
<div>
<form action="/Home/SignUp" name="signupForm">
    <p>
        <b>First Name:</b><br />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-model="fname" name="fname" />
        <span ng-show="signupForm.fname.$dirty&&signupForm.fname.$invalid" style="color:red">
            <span ng-show="signupForm.fname.$error.required">First Name is required</span>
        </span>

    </p>
    <p>
        <b>Last Name:</b><br />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-model="lname" name="lname"/>
        <span ng-show="signupForm.lname.$dirty&&signupForm.lname.$invalid" style="color:red">
            <span ng-show="signupForm.lname.$error.required">Last Name is required</span>
        </span>

    </p>
      <p>
        <b>Email:</b><br />
        <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-required="true" name="email" ng-model="email"/>
          <span ng-show="signupForm.email.$dirty&&signupForm.email.$invalid" style="color:red">
              <span ng-show="signupForm.email.$error.required">Email is required</span>
              <span ng-show="signupForm.email.$error.email"></span>
          </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>Age:</b><br />
        <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-model="age"/>
        <span ng-show="signupForm.age.$dirty&&signupForm.age.$invalid" style="color:red">
            <span ng-show="signupForm.age.$error.required">Age is required</span>
            <span ng-show="signupForm.age.$error.max ||signupForm.age.$error.min ">Age must be in between 18- 60 years</span>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>Password:</b><br />
        <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-model="password" name="password" ng-maxlength="16" ng-minlength="8"/>
        <span ng-show="signupForm.password.$dirty&&signupForm.password.$invalid" style="color:red">
            <span ng-show="signupForm.password.$error.required">Passowrd is required</span>
            <span ng-show="signupForm.password.$error.maxlength ||signupForm.password.$error.minlength "></span>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>Confirm Password:</b><br />
        <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-model="conPassword" name="conPassword" ng-maxlength="16" ng-minlength="8" ng-equal="password"/>
        <span ng-show="signupForm.conPassword.$dirty&&signupForm.conPassword.$invalid" style="color:red">
            <span ng-show="signupForm.conPassword.$error.required">Passowrd is required</span>
            <span ng-show="signupForm.conPassword.$error.maxlength ||signupForm.conPassword.$error.minlength "></span>
            <span ng-show="signupForm.conPassword.$error.equal">Password do not match</span>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>Upload Profile Picture:</b><br />
        <input type="file" value="Upload" /><input type="submit" value="Upload" ng-click="Upload()" ng-required="true"/>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="signupForm.$invalid"/>
</form>
```

I am Loading Partial View inside in ng-view in Index page but angular validation is not working inside the ng-view partial view . Please help anyone?